# how to pass parameters to a stored procedure using @NamedNativeQuery in spring hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures

i have a procedure that has a parameter @id, i am also calling the @NamedNativeQuery in spring hibernate, i want to know how to pass the parameter in the procedure in the query property of @NamedNativeQuery

my code looks like this.

@NamedNativeQuery(name = "Callmyprocedure", query="{CALL sampleprocedure :id}", callable =true, resultClass = Subscriber.class)

where id is my procedure parameter, but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```
@Entity  
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "SampleNameQuery",query = "call spS_NamedQuery(?,?)",resultSetMapping="mapping",resultClass = NamedQuery.class)  
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="mapping",columns=@ColumnResult(name="value"))        
public class NamedQuery {  

 @Id  
 public String name;  

 @Column  
 public String value;  
}  
                . . . .
```

And you pass the parameters like this:

```
 Transaction trx = null;  
  Session session = HibernateSessionFactory.getSession();  
  try {  
   trx = session.beginTransaction();  

   org.hibernate.Query query = session.getNamedQuery("SampleNameQuery");  
   query.setParameter(0,"fsdfsdf");         
   String value = "";  
   query.setParameter(1,value);         
   List objList = query.list();      
   trx.commit();
```

I hope it helped you.